CRM Dynamics 9.1 on-premises RDL invalid files
I just moved from Dynamics 8.2 (With SQL Server 2022 version) to 9.1. After installing Reporting services (v.2022) and Reporting extensions still getting this error on every report (custom and default):

For report design and creation, I use MS Report Builder. On 8.2 everything was working fine with that report designer.
Installed all up to date patches but still getting the same error.

It's usually best practice to type the error out within an indent or sets of ` rather than posting an image of it.

My bad, first time here :D
So I'm getting this error:
This report can’t upload. This issue can occur when the Report Definition Language (RDL) file is not valid. If you contact support, please provide the technical details.

@АшотАрзаканян - please don't post details like error messages in a comment. Instead, please edit your question and include the proper details. But also, right now this isn't a programming question - it's something specific to Dynamics.
